# How is the cardinality determined in a query?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two queries which return the same result set, but when reviewing the execution plans they have different values of cardinality.

The queries are:

```
select acq_cod
    , prp
    , df_val
    , descr
from acqdefprp
where (prp like '%pswd%' or prp like '%Pswd%')
    and prp not like '%kno%'
    and prp not like '%encr%';
```

and

```
select acq_cod
       , prp
       , df_val
       , descr
from acqdefprp
where regexp_instr(prp, 'pswd', 1,1,0,'i' ) > 0
    and regexp_instr(prp, '(encr)|(kno)', 1,1,0,'i' ) = 0;
```

The first query has the following explain plan:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |            |    65 |  4485 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| acqdefprp  |    65 |  4485 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(("PRP" LIKE '%pswd%' OR "PRP" LIKE '%Pswd%') 
           AND "PRP" NOT LIKE '%kno%' 
           AND "PRP" NOT LIKE '%encr%')
```

And the explain plan for the second query is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |            |    1  |    69 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| acqdefprp  |    1  |    69 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(REGEXP_INSTR ("PRP",'(encr)|(kno)',1,1,0,'i') = 0
           AND REGEXP_INSTR ("PRP",'pswd',1,1,0,'i') > 0 )
```

My question is why is the cardinality different between the two execution plans? For the first plan the cardinality (rows) is 65 and for the second it's 1?

My **assumption** is that this cardinality is the maximum number of rows that will be returned by each condition, if each condition was evaluated separately, and all of this based on table statistics. And that is why for my first query this assumed maximum is 65, since the `WHERE` conditions are a little more permissive.

And also that is why for the second query the cardinality is 1, since the `regexp_instr` is more restrictive.

If my assumptions are not correct, I'd really like to know what determines this cardinality number.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: The CBO pretty complex. There are statistics, dynamic_sampling which may be used for cost, and many other things which are used for plan.

Answer (score 5):

In your case the expression are too complex for the optimizer to use basic statistics to estimate the cardinality. In these cases (it doesn't seem that you use histograms that might affect `LIKE` predicates) a fixed selectivity is used:

equality operator: 1%
inequality operator: 5%

So your

`LIKE` example is approximately `(5 % + 5 % - (5 % * 5 %)) * 95 % * 95 % => 8.8 %` of total table rows.  `- (5 % * 5 %)` is the intersection because of `OR` operator.

`REGEX` example is `1 % * 5 % => 0.05 %` of total table rows.

Oracle also supports extended statistics where you can compute statistics and histograms for specific expressions or correlated columns.

Comment: The entire table has 779 rows, so 0.05% would be 0.3895 rows (I'm assuming it will round up to 1) and 8.8% is 68.552 rows (so I'd round up to 69). Your answer seems close (65 rows returned for the 1st query and 1 row for the 2nd, but where did you get the percentage for the equality operators?

Comment: Oracle usually ceils the decimals. It never estimates 0 rows, always at least one (depends also on undocumented parameters), even with contradiction 1 = 0 or NULL IS NOT NULL as it uses it in execution plans. Check ALL_TAB_STATISTICS.NUM_ROWS for the total rows used when generating execution plan (the stats might be different than current number of rows in the table). I haven't found the percentages in the documentation but it's well know fact. You may google many references and for learning how Oracle optimizer works I definitely recommend Jonathan Lewis' book Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals.

Comment: @Husqvik I tries extended statistics for    `DBMS_STATS.create_extended_stats(null, 'TST','(regexp_instr(prp, ''999'', 1,1,0,''i'' ))')` but failed with error of two magnitudes. Can you verify? For `column LIKE '%xxx%'` I don't see possibility for extended statistics ..

Comment: Extended statistics are only for cases of correlated columns or functions, LIKE can use only histograms, and only when % or _ not at the beginning. With REGEX I haven't been able to see any impact, it always used the guesstimates. I just mentioned the extended statistics for reference not that they should be used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You comapare plans with direct `WHERE` conditions and with `REGEXP_INSTR` functions. Actually there is no difference which function to use, for oracle very difficult to give a real estimate without function execution.

For example we can create function -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_check(str IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   IF str LIKE 'A%' THEN
      RETURN 1;
   END IF;
  RETURN -1;
END;
/
```

First select -

```
SELECT *
  FROM tmptxt
 WHERE dsc LIKE 'A%'

Plan hash value: 2928917536

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |   121 |  4356 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMPTXT |   121 |  4356 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DSC" LIKE 'A%')
```

and with function -

```
SELECT *
  FROM tmptxt
 WHERE f_check(dsc) = 1


Plan hash value: 2928917536

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |     1 |    36 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMPTXT |     1 |    36 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("F_CHECK"("DSC")=1)
```

This two queries give the same result, but plan estimate has some difference. It is not too important (fullscan in first way and fullscan in the second), just need to evaluate the whole plan, didn't dwell on the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

*My assumption is that this cardinality is the maximum number of rows that will be returned by each condition....*

No, **cardinality** is the estimation of the CBO how many rows will be returned in the operation. (technicaly always >= 1).

The cardinality is calculated either from the object statistics stored in data dictionary or by **dynaming sampling** (details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#PFGRF94759)).

Dynamic sampling are more costly (as they are calculated in each parse) but can return much precise results.

So one possible **workaround** to get better estimation is to use dynamic sampling. Here small demo with level 10 (which is **extrem and demo only** as the whole table is scanned in parsing step; but it is not a problem with 779 rows table and the **cardinatlity is exact**)

```
 create table tst as 
 select ltrim(to_char(rownum,'09999')) prp from dual connect by level <= 999999;


 select count(*) from tst where prp like '%999%';

 280 

 select count(*) from tst where regexp_instr(prp, '999', 1,1,0,'i' ) > 0;

 280

 Alter session set optimizer_dynamic_sampling=10;

EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
select  * from tst where prp like '%999%';

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL')); 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   280 |  1400 |   467   (2)| 00:00:06 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TST  |   280 |  1400 |   467   (2)| 00:00:06 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 - filter("PRP" IS NOT NULL AND "PRP" LIKE '%999%')

EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
select  * from tst where regexp_instr(prp, '999', 1,1,0,'i' ) > 0;

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL')); 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   280 |  1400 |   479   (5)| 00:00:06 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TST  |   280 |  1400 |   479   (5)| 00:00:06 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter( REGEXP_INSTR ("PRP",'999',1,1,0,'i')>0)
```